# How do I make a div jump back to its original position after it animates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, html, position

I'm having trouble figuring out callbacks, or whatever this is. I'm using some jquery addon called easing and what is supposed to happen is you click a button, and a div flies in from the left, then when you click on the x on that div, it flies out the right. Problem is, when you click it again it flies in from the right and out the right. What I want to do is have the div appear back at its original position when the animation finishes playing.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function(event) {
        $('#animdiv')
            .animate(
                { left: 170 }, {
                    duration: 'slow',
                    easing: 'easeOutBack'
                });
});
    $('#exit').click(function(event) {
        $('#animdiv')
            .animate(
                { left: 1200 }, {
                    duration: 'slow',
                    easing: 'easeOutBack'
                });
    });
});
// this is the function that takes it back to it's original place
function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.getElementById('animdiv');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = -600;
  d.style.top = 32;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) takes a callback function which will run  only after the animation is complete:

```
$('#exit').click(function(event) {
    $('#animdiv')
        .animate(
            { left: 1200 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeOutBack',
                complete: placeDiv
            });
});
```

However, your `placeDiv` function won't work until you add `px` to your styles:

```
function placeDiv() {
  var d = document.getElementById('animdiv');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = "-600px";
  d.style.top = "32px";
}
```

or else use jQuery (which will add the `px` for you):

```
function placeDiv() {
  $('#animdiv').css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: -600,
    top: 32
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/M6xGC/

---

Or, if you want to pass the x and y values:

```
$('#exit').click(function (event) {
    var xpos = -600,
        ypos = 32;
    $('#animdiv')
        .animate({
        left: 1200
    }, {
        duration: 'slow',
        easing: 'easeOutBack',
        complete: function() { placeDiv(xpos,ypos); }
    });
});
```

and the callback:

```
function placeDiv(x,y) {
  $('#animdiv').css({
    position: "absolute",
    left: x,
    top: y
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/M6xGC/4/

Comment: I moved the function to the top and added in the line and comma but it doesn't work for me. I'm not getting any errors either so I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Haha, didn't know there was a callback for after animation complete. Use that. Forget my answer.

Couple of ways of doing this -

1. The div flying out can happen from right to left. In that case all you need to do is change left value of exit click -

   ```
   $('#exit').click(function(event) {
       $('#animdiv')
           .animate(
               { left: -600 }, {
                   duration: 'slow',
                   easing: 'easeOutBack'
               });
   });
   ```
2. Before you animate the entry, hide the div, reposition to -600px, change to display: block again and then animate -

   ```
   $('#button').click(function(event) {
       $('#animdiv').hide().css('left', '-600px').show()
           .animate(
               { left: 170 }, {
                   duration: 'slow',
                   easing: 'easeOutBack'
               });
   ```